# Where should I put a Python module for Python 2.7 on OS X?

Tags: macos, python-2.7

For different version of Mac OS X (10.6, 10.7, and 10.8), can I install a python module to same location?

where should I copy a python module to?

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

or

`/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`   ?

Or by other words, is `sys.path` the same for python2.7 on different versions of Mac OS X?

Thanks.

LJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/Library/Python/2.n/site-packages/` where n = 5,6,7 is the default `site-packages` directory for the Apple-supplied system Pythons in OS X, e.g. `/usr/bin/python2.n`,

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/m.n/lib/pythonm.n/site-packages` is the default `site-packages` directory for some user-installed Pythons in OS X, most notably those from python.org-supplied binary installers for OS X, usually `/usr/local/bin/pythonm.n`.

It is normally not necessary to deal with the details of `site-packages` directly.  Nearly all modern third-party packages for Python use the particular Python's built-in Distutils for installation, i.e. they have a `setup.py` file:

`/usr/bin/python2.7 setup.py install` -> installs to `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`

`/usr/local/bin/python2.7 setup.py install` -> installs to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

For your own packages, you should use a `setup.py` as well.

At a higher level, install `pip` for each of the Pythons you are using and use those pips to manage package installations so you don't need to directly deal with downloading or with `setup.py`.

`/usr/bin/python2.7 -m pip install package-name`

`/usr/local/bin/python2.7 -m pip install package-name`

Also `virtualenv`s are an approach to managing multiple `site-packages`.